# Nombre mes a numero mes C#

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

Necesito obtener el numero de un mes según su nombre.

Ejemplo: // **Febrero = 2** // **Diciembre = 12** //

En todos los docs y foros que he leído sale lo que ya intente, pero no logro entender por que a mi me da error.

Método:

```
int numeromes = DateTime.ParseExact("Enero", "MMMM", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture).Month;
```

Error:

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Comment: Hola KennyAli agrega que realizas con el valor numeromes, ya que el error "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime." puede estar en otra parte.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me temo que tu problema es que tu `CurrentCulture` no es español por alguna razón. El siguiente código devuelve correctamente el numero de mes:

```
CultureInfo cult = new CultureInfo("es-ES", false);
int numeromes = DateTime.ParseExact("Enero", "MMMM", cult).Month;
```

Answer (score 0):

No deberías tener ningún problema usando :

```
    using System.Globalization;

...

 int numeromes = DateTime.ParseExact("Octubre", "MMMM", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture).Month;
 Console.WriteLine("El número de mes es: " + numeromes);
```

Esto si tu Culture es en idioma español por ejemplo yo tengo "es-MX", pero si es de otro idioma eso provocaría error, por ejemplo para tu país Nicaragua podrías definir "es-ES", de esta forma :

```
  int numeromes = DateTime.ParseExact("Octubre", "MMMM", new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("es-ES")).Month;
  Console.WriteLine("El número de mes es:  " + numeromes);
```

Sin embargo, por el error que comentas:

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

el problema puede estar en otra parte del código.